# Can some one please suggest any open source tool for BIg Data Automation Testing

Tags: automation

"I am started learning Big Data Testing and I would to automate big data use case. I did not find much information about open source tool for big data automation."Can some please suggest any open soruce tool

Comment: This platform is for providing solutions to specific problems. You can search on google or relevant platform for this question.

Comment: No problem. You may wanna have a look at 'Presto'.